# How to find exceptions in code that is not executed?

Tags: python

In this simple Python code if the value of `a` is changed from `0` then there will be a `NameError` showing that `b` is undefined. However, if the `else` clause is never executed, the error remains hidden. How can I detect these kind of errors?

```
a=0
if a==0 :
  print "hello"
else :
  print b
```

Comment: pylint will catch that kind of errors

Comment: Create a [decorator](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/) to suppress the error and print/write to log the exceptions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470/are-there-static-analysis-tools-for-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) is able to find a lot of common (and not so common) errors in python code without executing it, example output from your example:

```
C:  1, 0: Exactly one space required around assignment
a=0
 ^ (bad-whitespace)
C:  2, 0: Exactly one space required around comparison
if a==0 :
    ^^ (bad-whitespace)
C:  2, 0: No space allowed before :
if a==0 :
        ^ (bad-whitespace)
C:  4, 0: No space allowed before :
else :
     ^ (bad-whitespace)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  1, 0: Invalid constant name "a" (invalid-name)
E:  5,10: Undefined variable 'b' (undefined-variable)
```

The line you're interested in here is: `E:  5,10: Undefined variable 'b' (undefined-variable)`

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Either include such statements within the [`try/except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) block. For example:

   ```
   >>> a = 1
   >>> if a == 0:
   ...     print a
   ... else:
   ...     try:
   ...         print b
   ...     except Exception as e:
   ...         print 'Caught Exception: ', e  # where e is the exception string
   ...
   Caught Exception:  name 'b' is not defined
   ```

   Use may also use [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) to get all the information related to raised `Exception`.
2. If you want this behavior at the scope of function, create a [`decorator`](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) and use that decorator with the functions you need this behavior.

---

Comment: If `a` is defined as `a = 0` (as in the OP's example), the `else` clause will never execute